# Does "ostensibly " make sense in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

Does ostensibly make sense in this sentence?

> An ostensibly perfect world destroys itself

What I'm trying to convey is

> A so-called perfect world destroyed itself

But *so-called* is not very academic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *ostensibly* - "As appears or is stated to be true, though not necessarily so; apparently." 
If that is the meaning you're want to imply by using that word, then yes, it works. A good way to find alternatives to words is by looking at synonyms in a thesaurus.

Comment: Google Scholar returns "about 5,670,000 results" for me for *so-called*, so I don't know the basis for your considering it "not very academic."

Comment: @choster "so-called" implies that someone is being deceitful.  "ostensibly" is more neutral.  All of these word-choice questions require loads of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ostensibly* does make sense here, but its meaning, although close to that of *so-called*, is not quite the same. As can be seen from Gwendolyn's comment, *ostensibly* is largely synonymous with *apparently*; the first sentence thus implies that the world appeared perfect, but it does not imply that anybody ever called it perfect. On the other hand, *so-called* in the second sentence makes it imply that people in fact used the word *perfect* to characterize the world, but it does not imply that they actually regarded is as perfect (they could have been using the word insincerely).